# How to retrieve a mean number into matlab GUI from cell string?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-guide

I am building a matlab GUI to retrieve an average PnL number from a 1047*1 double cell string called pnl_P1 into edit text window called (function Average_PnL_Pair_1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)). What is the simplest or very simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you post an example of the input data?

Comment: in function Start_visualization_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)...i have the following....cumi_P1 = evalin('base', 'cumi_P1'); axes(handles.PnL_Pair_1_axes) plot('cumi_P1, 'DisplayName', 'cumi_P1', 'YDataSource', 'cumi_P1'); guidata(hObject, handles); then in the axis....function Period_PnL_Pair_1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) % handles structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA) cumi_P1 = evalin('base','cumi_P1'); plot(cumi_P1) guidata(hObject, handles); %updates the handles .....how can import this cumi_P1 from workspace and get the axis to plot it? input.d 1047*1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want `mean(cellfun(@str2double, pnl_P1))`?

Comment: 1 column 1047 rows of 0,0, .02, 0, -0.2 etc. all I want to do is to get the GUI to show this number (mean of) after excluding all the 0 values into one of the edit text boxes...does this make sense? so what do i type in the function Average_PnL_Pair_1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

Comment: pn1_P1=pnl_P1;
set(handles.Period_PnL_Pair_1,'String',mean(cell2mat(handles.pnl_P1)));

Comment: in function Start_visualization_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)...i have the following....cumi_P1 = evalin('base', 'cumi_P1'); axes(handles.PnL_Pair_1_axes) plot('cumi_P1, 'DisplayName', 'cumi_P1', 'YDataSource', 'cumi_P1'); guidata(hObject, handles); then in the axis....function Period_PnL_Pair_1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) % handles structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA) cumi_P1 = evalin('base','cumi_P1'); plot(cumi_P1) guidata(hObject, handles); %updates the handles .....how can import this cumi_P1 from workspace and get the axis to plot it ??? –

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly I'd do the following.

Do not store numbers in cell string array, but if you must, use mean(cell2mat(pnl_P1)) to get the mean value. Create a value under handles so you can reach your pnl_P1 vector from anywhere.

```
handles.pnl_P1 = pnl_P1;
```

Make sure you always update your handles after each function in your GUI. It is strongly recommended. 
% Update handles structure

```
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Insert value into edit box:

```
set(handles.edit1,'String',mean(cell2mat(handles.pnl_P1)));
```

handles.edit1 is the tag handle for the edit box you want to update.

What is the tag for your edit box?
Simple: in guide right-click on your edit box, select properties inspector, scroll down to Tag. If it says edit1 then use handles.edit1 and so on.

If you are new to Matlab GUIs I recommend [this.](http://blinkdagger.com/matlab/) They have stopped updating it but it's a great learning source.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks this is becomming more understandable now: The tag for my edit box is Period_PnL_Pair_1.

Comment: pn1_P1=pnl_P1;
set(handles.Period_PnL_Pair_1,'String',mean(cell2mat(handles.pnl_P1))); but its not working

Comment: Here is an example that works for me.

a = {'0','2','4','564','-45'};
set(handles.edit1,'String',mean(cell2mat(a)));

There must be something wrong with your variables or handles.

try

set(handles.Period_PnL_Pair_1,'String','I am working'); 
If it says 'I am working' in your edit box the variable is wrong.


Are you sure you set this variable handles.pnl_P1?
you could try<br/>
disp(handles.pnl_P1) <br/>and check your command window if the variable was printed out.

Comment: how do i define my onl_P1 in GUI to the matrix in my matlab workspace that contains all the data called pnl_P1?

Comment: The workspace data you want to use must be loaded into your gui the same way you load in any data to a normal function. GUIs normally use varargin (if you don't know what it is type: 'doc varargin' into the command window.

Comment: If you have a GUI called test. Under the opening function [function test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)]. You add if ~isempty(varargin{1}) handles.mydata = varargin{1} end... and then you can always reach handles.mydata

Comment: ok. I have maybe ten data sets that i need to load from matlab workace into gui. do i define them in vrargout in the begining or hat is the fastest way to move this data into gui? i then need to call the data into various aces in gui and into edit text boxes etcc....

Comment: in function Start_visualization_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)...i have the following....cumi_P1 = evalin('base', 'cumi_P1'); 
axes(handles.PnL_Pair_1_axes)
plot('cumi_P1, 'DisplayName', 'cumi_P1', 'YDataSource', 'cumi_P1');

guidata(hObject, handles);   then in the axis....function Period_PnL_Pair_1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)   % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
cumi_P1 = evalin('base','cumi_P1');
plot(cumi_P1)
guidata(hObject, handles); %updates the handles
.....how can import this cumi_P1 from workspace and get the axis to plot it ???